# Error al usar HttpModules en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Resulta que estoy usando httpModules para controlar los eventos AuthenticateRequest y AuthorizeRequest en la aplicación. En el web.config lo tengo vinculado en las siguientes etiquetas:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
         <add type="Proyecto.App.UI.CustomAuthenticationModule" name="CustomAuthenticationModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

El proyecto no tiene errores de compilación, por lo que se ejecuta correctamente. Sin embargo, el error lo estoy obteniendo en el front-end, y la consola del navegador (Google Chrome) arroja lo siguiente:

[image: Consola Google Chrome]

Esto provoca que los eventos con ajax no funcionen (autocompletar en textbox).

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?. Al quitar el httpModules, la aplicación funciona correctamente.

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿En algun sitio de tu javascript estas llamando a Sys.WebForms o parecido? Por lo que veo en otras questiones parecidas es algun problema a la hora de cuando o como estas llamando a ese javascript

Comment: @Mulflar No. Yo descartaría en que el error está en javascript, debido que al quitar el HttpModules de la aplicación, ésta funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

con qué tipo de canalización tienes configurado tu App Pool?

Si usas **Canalización Clásica** entonces debes definir tu HttpModule en el web.config de la siguiente forma

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add type="Proyecto.App.UI.CustomAuthenticationModule" name="CustomAuthenticationModule"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Si usas **Canalización Integrada** entonces debes definir tu HttpModule en el web.config de la siguiente forma

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add type="Proyecto.App.UI.CustomAuthenticationModule" name="CustomAuthenticationModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

También revisaría si tienes establecido en tu web.config tanto el HttpHandler como el HttpModule para la configuración de AJAX (verifica los números de versión con los que trabajas)

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ya había probado todo lo anterior, pero nada de eso fue útil para mi. Lo bueno es que ya encontré la solución, pronto compartiré la respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Francisco. Puedes compartir la solución? Gracias